Postman path variables in the middle of URL path segment
Is there a way in Postman to create a path variable that does not start at the slash character? The API that I'm working with is constructed like this:
{{baseUrl}}/path/to/the/resource/:parentEntityId/code=:childEntityCode
Postman seems to be able to recognise only the first variable (parentEntityId) while being completely blind to the second one (childEntityCode). Is there some kind of escaping mechanism built into the colon-syntax that allows variables to be included mid-segment in the URL path section.
